# Hover on ASP .NET Menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, menu

I have used an asp .net menu in a div. I need to display the menu by mouse hover on another div element called "Menu".

The problem is that the menu disappears when the mouse moves onto the menu [away from the "Menu" div], thus making the menu non accessible.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".heading").hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".txtcontent").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="heading" style="width: 100%; font-size: 7pt; font-family: 'Lucida Bright';">
<span style="font-size: 20pt">MENU</span>
</div>
<div class="txtcontent" style="width: 90%; display: none;">
<asp:Menu> Menu contents </asp:Menu>
<div>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/SJHr5/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
<div class="heading" style="width: 100%; font-size: 7pt; font-family: 'Lucida Bright';">
<span style="font-size: 20pt">MENU</span>

<div class="txtcontent" style="width: 90%; display: none;">
    <asp:Menu> Menu contents </asp:Menu>

</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(function() {
    $(".heading").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".txtcontent").slideDown("slow");

    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".txtcontent").slideUp("slow");


    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks.It works but has a bug. When a submenu opens from the asp .net menu and the mouse moves out of the control, it does not slide up.

Comment: @sanjay_c0d3r cool, man we will fix it, flick me a fiddle, i.e. use the demo above and create the issue, will flick solution your way. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

When you hover the Menu item, the menu is shown as you expected but when you move the mouse to the menu itself, the Menu item is no longer hovered, so, what you need to do is get the `txtcontent` that holds the menu inside the menu item.

You can do it in this way:

```
<div class="heading" style="width: 100%; font-size: 7pt; font-family: 'Lucida Bright';">
    <div style="font-size:20pt;position:relative;display:inline-block;">
        <span>Menu</span>
        <div class="txtcontent" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:25px;left:0;">
            <asp:Menu> Menu contents </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No just give the menu (`txtcontent`) the style you want.. fix the top position i gave here etc...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what you want by doing the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading").mouseover(function () {
        jQuery(this).next(".txtcontent").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    jQuery(".txtcontent").mouseout(function () {
        jQuery(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

notice this will not work correctly when there are multiple headings, each .txtcontent will remain visible until you go over it, and then leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution in addition to posted above :)

```
var hideMenuTimeout = null;

jQuery(".heading").hover(
function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".txtcontent").slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
    var self = this;
    hideMenuTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(self).next(".txtcontent").slideUp("slow");
    }, 100);
});

$(".txtcontent").hover(
function() {
    clearTimeout(hideMenuTimeout);
}, function() {
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/d5yt5/)